# how to close a channel factory correctly?

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory, servicehost

I would like to know how to close a channelFactory correctly. Actually, I'm using:

```
try
{
   factory.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
}
catch
{
   factory.Abort();
}
```

But to the ServiceHost side, and unhandled exception reach the domain level (top level of the app).
I don't understand why the service host don't catch the exception and handle it with the IErrorHandler that I configure.

This is how I configure the ErrorHandler:

```
IErrorHandler handler = new ErrorHandler();
foreach (var channelDispatcher in host.ChannelDispatchers.Select(d => d as ChannelDispatcher).Where(d => d != null))
{
    channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(handler);
}
```

Comment: Show us how you set up the IErrorHandler

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your factory is null before calling Abort():

```
try
{
    factory.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25))
}
catch
{
    if (factory != null)
    {
        factory.Abort();
    }
    throw;
}
```